# create xml entry with same element instance python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a large XML file and I want to get specific values of entries from it into a new XML file (and that will reduce the size from the large XML file into the new XML file)

Now I Write the above code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
from lxml import etree   

dst = "/root/Downloads/lilmalxml.xml"
dsttemp = "/root/Downloads/malxml.xml"

filehandler = etree.parse(dsttemp)
rootElement = etree.Element("list")  
doc = etree.ElementTree(rootElement)

for entry in filehandler.xpath("///entry"):
    virusname = entry.find("virusname").text
    url = entry.find("url").text
    ip = entry.find("ip").text
    formatstr = "<url ip='{0}' virusname='{1}'><![CDATA[{2}]]></url>".format(ip,virusname,url)      
    sub = etree.fromstring(formatstr)
    rootElement.append(sub)

f = open(dst,"w")
doc.write(f,encoding='utf-8',method='xml')
f.close()   
print "FINISHED"
```

The line `rootElement.append(sub)` appends the new entry, but it goes on the same instance of every new sub that is created. (it overrides the element again and again)

By the way, the large XML entry looks like this

```
<entry>
    <line>1</line>
    <id>88871349</id>
    <first>1456571225</first>
    <last>0</last>
    <md5></md5>
    <virustotal>http://www.virustotal.com/latest-report.html?resource=b637e57062280a903ee05f397feeea24</virustotal>
    <vt_score>27/56 (48.2%)</vt_score>
    <scanner>undef</scanner>
    <virusname><![CDATA[Generic7.RAL]]></virusname>
    <url><![CDATA[http://xiazaiqi2.xpgod.com/down/yy%20at%20134_1062.exe]]></url>
    <recent>up</recent>
    <response>alive</response>
    <ip>222.186.130.206</ip>
    <as>AS4134</as>
    <review>61.164.110.151</review>
    <domain>xpgod.com</domain>
    <country>CN</country>
    <source>APNIC</source>
    <email>anti_spam@wz.zj.cn</email>
    <inetnum>61.164.108.0 - 61.164.111.255</inetnum>
    <netname>RUIAN-TELECOM</netname>
    <descr><![CDATA[Ruian Telecom]]></descr>
    <ns1>ns3.dnsv3.com</ns1>
    <ns2>ns4.dnsv3.com</ns2>
    <ns3></ns3>
    <ns4></ns4>
    <ns5></ns5>
</entry>
```

Do you have any other way for adding an entry, but in the same format as I did?

Comment: I see different `url` elements created in the output file. Not sure what are you asking about. What is your desired output? Thanks.

Comment: when I try to open that on gedit it stucks and if I open it on Leafpad it show mess with the xml everything override everything. what I mean by override is that the elements override themselves and it looks like it big mess and unclear elements

Comment: Okay, what about `doc.write(f,encoding='utf-8',method='xml', pretty_print=True)`?

Comment: wow I didn't think about that! it works like magic! thank you very much!!